# autolayout issue in some table view cell only

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am a beginner in iOS development, and now i am trying to learn to make Instagram clone app. i have 3 table view cell in one table view controller

1. a static header cell
2. media cell to show up the photo
3. a comment cell

and I have set the autolayout constraint for all those 3 table view cells, per the screenshot below

[image]

but when i run the app, the header cell and the comment cell have some autolayout issues. but the media cell seems okay, it construct as i want it. it seems that the comment cell and header cell attached to the top left side of the table view cell container

[image]

the profile picture image view makes me suspicious, because if i delete the profile picture and just put the username and follow button, the autolayout worked.

i put this contraints for the profile image : top, leading and bottom space constraint to view + aspect ratio

i don't know why the autolayout issue only occured for header and comment cell. the media cell is perfect as i am expected

Comment: are you using `UITableViewController` or  `UITableView` in `UIViewController`

Comment: i am using UITableViewController

Comment: yeah that is causing the problem try in  the viewController or wait for my answer

Comment: Add width and height constraint on profile image view

Comment: see my answer @AgungLaksana