# Constraints ignored when using xib/nib in xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, constraints, xib

Just to preface, this issue is similar to the problem of constraints being ignored in prototype cells, but I have tried all of the recommendations on this site and none have worked. I've tried:

- [Autolayout is ignored in Custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319921/autolayout-is-ignored-in-custom-uitableviewcell/48162911#48162911)
- [iOS TableView Constraints doesn’t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012524/ios-tableview-constraints-doesn-t-work?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [autolayout issue in some table view cell only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974639/autolayout-issue-in-some-table-view-cell-only?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Constraints not working in TableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707627/constraints-not-working-in-tableviewcell?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Autolayout is ignored in custom TableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027017/autolayout-is-ignored-in-custom-tableviewcell?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My app uses xib/nib files, which I guess makes it even more of a pain for fixing.

I have set up the table inside of a UIView and included a prototype cell that is connected to the xib, like so:

[image]

[image]

I added constraints for each element and even made sure that xcode added any I forgot. I did not use stack view, because when I do it collapses everything on top of one another.

[image]

However, regardless of what I try, when I go to run it, I still get this:

[image]

The view, is a UIView in the Interface builder. The table is a UITableView. The prototype cell is a EpisodeTableViewCell (name of the xib). And the Xib is a EpisodeTableViewCell.

Attempts that did not work:

- Setting the prototype cell to standard UITableViewCell
- Removing the prototype cell
- Setting more constraints
- Setting stack layout
- Various attempts to more closely link the xib and the main views.

And some other stuff I've tried that I'm not remembering at this time. I've been trying to fix this for days now. I'm open to any new suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE WITH XIB INFO**

The xib is connected through the prototype cell and some code. The prototype cell is set as the name of the xib, but is also a button to direct the user to the next view.

[image]

[image]

```
episodeListTableView.delegate = self
    episodeListTableView.dataSource = self
    episodeListTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "EpisodeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SingleEpisodeTableViewCell")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your cell nib code? I think issue is with constraints. If not then probably the hight for `UITableViewCell` is wrong.

Comment: Apparently, the UI for your cell can also be achieved by setting your cell style to `Subtitle` Don't need to create a custom one. Not sure though.

Comment: Most people with similar issues didn't find that it was a code issue. Just some weird problem with Interface builder. 
But changing the height using 

self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120 // Any referencial height

Doesn't actually work in this instance.

Comment: *"a prototype cell that is connected to the xib"* ... how are you doing that? Generally, one uses XIB files *instead of* Storyboards and prototypes. I just did a quick test, and using `tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SingleEpisodeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SECell")` I have no problem with auto-layout respecting the constraints.

Comment: Unfortunately, without the prototype cell, I can't use the cell as a button to the next view, or I would just do away with the prototype all together. I included some new images above for more detail about the xib connection.

Comment: I guess the question becomes, if this is an error in xcode somehow because I have some random thing set improperly somewhere, do I just need to set all the constraints programmatically?

Comment: @adazebra - I'll whip up a quick example for you when I get home (check back in a couple hours).

Comment: Awesome, that would be amazing.

Comment: Added a code snippet above that was important.

Comment: Are your cells fixed height? Or should they auto-size based on multi-line labels?

Comment: Well, hard to say why you're having your issues, without seeing all of your code / xibs / etc. Here is an example, though. Laid-out basically how you have shown... it uses auto-sizing cells (the bottom label has Zero lines, so it will wrap with enough text). https://github.com/DonMag/XIBTableCells

Comment: It all looks the same. I can only guess that there's some weird setting in the interface builder that's screwing the whole thing up.

Comment: @adazebra - it sounds more like you're missing a constraint (or two). Look very closely.

Comment: I used the button that fills in missing constraints. My coding partner just changed the whole thing from interface builder to code. So I guess it's over at this point.